# Почему try_files в nginx не видит файл на диске

Tags: nginx, location

Всем привет. 
Есть у меня недопонимание по конфигу nginx.
Есть у меня location

```
location ~* ^/resize/(.*)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$ {
    try_files /var/image-gallery/php/web/assert/$1/$4_$2_$3 /resize.php?storage=$1&width=$2&height=$3&file=$4&ext=$5;
}
```

Если файл есть, то хочу его напрямую отдавать. Иначе отдавать на ресайз.
Пример http запроса

http://host:8000/resize/storage3/100/100/28f686ecb64bbb0c90d824a4be08a1e9.jpeg

На диске файл лежит по адресу

```
$ file /var/image-gallery/php/web/assert/storage3/28f686ecb64bbb0c90d824a4be08a1e9_100_100.jpeg
/var/image-gallery/php/web/assert/storage3/28f686ecb64bbb0c90d824a4be08a1e9_100_100.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 100x100, frames 3
```

Но nginx  постоянно отправляет файл на ресайз.

Почему он не видит файл на диске?

Comment: А где же`$5`? Вы расширение файла потеряли

Comment: А во-вторых, try_files ищет от корня сайта заданного директивой root

Comment: Вы правы. Я на английской версии ответил сам же себе, а тут забыл. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853269/nginx-try-files-not-working-regexp?noredirect=1#comment80654330_46853269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел сам в тот же день. 
Вот мой вопрос на англ. версии https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853269/nginx-try-files-not-working-regexp

Я использовал абсолютный путь для файловой системы, а nginx абсолютный путь принимает как относительный от директивы root

Починил так:

```
location ~* ^/resize/(.*)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$ {
   root /var/image-gallery/php/web/assert;
   try_files /$1/$4_$2_$3.$5 /resize.php?storage=$1&width=$2&height=$3&file=$4&ext=$5;
}
```